# Linq-Query Equivalent for a SQL-Statement

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have to generate a List of IDs (int) from a table with Linq-Query for specific Conditions (count of specific column = 0).

In SQL having a Statement like:

```
select id 
from person 
where (select count(*) from mitgliedschaft 
       where mitgliedschaft.person_id = person.id 
         AND (austritt IS NULL OR austritt > getDate())) = 0
```

Trying to do this with Linq:

```
List<int> personIDsOhneAktuelleMitgliedschaft = db.mitgliedschaft
    .Where(x => x.deletedFlag == 0 && (x.austritt == null || x.austritt > DateTime.Now))
    .Select(x => x.person_id.Value)
    .ToList();
```

I dont know how to set it up, to check the count = 0 in the where-part!

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your LINQ query you can do something like this:

```
var personIDsOhneAktuelleMitgliedschaft = db.mitgliedschaft
    .Where(x => x.deletedFlag == 0 && (x.austritt == null || x.austritt > DateTime.Now))
    .Select(x => x.person_id.Value);

var result = db.Person
    .Where(x => !personIDsOhneAktuelleMitgliedschaft.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(x => x.Id);
```

Structuring your EF model with [navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) will simplify your queries.

Answer (score 0):

In `Where` you have to put LINQ subquery. Exactly as for SQL. Also you do not need Count for such filter NOT EXISTS is enough and it has analogue in LINQ - `!Any`.

```cs
var query = db.Person
    .Where(p => !db.mitgliedschaft.Any(x => x.person_id == p.Id && x.deletedFlag == 0 && (x.austritt == null || x.austritt > DateTime.Now)))
    .Select(p => p.Id);
```